# Am I allowed to use element from a parent block, inside a children block?

Tags: html, css, bem

I would like to know if, according to BEM methodology, I can have the following structure:

```
.block1
  .block1__element1
    .block2
       .block1__element2 <-- ??
```

Am I allowed to use an element from a parent block, inside a children block?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This is the actual DOM structure:

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="head__user"></div>
  <div class="head__nav">
    <div class="menu">
       // <-- ???
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to best practices of BEM methodology: am I allowed to move the element with `head__user` inside the `menu` block? Or all elements inside the `menu` block need to start with the `menu__` prefix?

I hope this clears out the problem.

Comment: What did you mean block elements? like what? could you provide a HTML sample?

Comment: Be specific and add some code or inspirational image for better understanding.

Comment: I've updated the question , thanks for your feedback.

Comment: they would have to start with `menu__` check my answer below as it might clear out some thoughts of yours.

Comment: @Dejan.S no, they wouldn't have to. Can you show me something about it in [the docs](https://en.bem.info/methodology/)?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov if we look at this part of the documentation https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#block, if we chop the design above, I would say that the recommendation is not to use it, as you suggest. But to each is own how to read the documentation.

Comment: @Dejan.S which part of this documentation has the recommendation is not to use it? I can't find anything like this. And, for example, if you use not `.menu` block, but [Bootstrap's Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width) and classes `.container`/`.row`/`.col`, then what? Can't you use these classes with your block's elements? Why?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov The OP is clearly starting a new block, as in the code is `block2`. They way I'm working with BEM I would never mix `block1__element` inside of `block2`. There is a difference in what you mean, you can use BS inside of your `block1`, but that is different then having `block1__element` inside of `block2`, why not add `block3` and have `block1__element` and a `block2__element` inside of that? You get the point I'm trying to make? If the documentation does not say that is illegal, does not make it ok to do so! The main point is to separate the point you are tying to make to mine

Comment: @Dejan.S then you shouldn't say "This is not correct" and "Based on this part of the documentation.", it's not true. It should be "I don't like this way" and "Based on my personal preferences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this variant is allowed:

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="head__nav">
    <div class="menu">
       <div class="head__user"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I haven't found the current part in [the official BEM documentation](https://en.bem.info/methodology/), but I've found [this part](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#nesting-1):

> The block name defines the namespace, which [guarantees that the](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#element-name) elements are dependent on the block (`block__elem`).
>
> A block can have a nested structure of elements in the DOM tree:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <div class="block">
>     <div class="block__elem1">
>         <div class="block__elem2">
>             <div class="block__elem3"></div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> However, this block structure is always represented as a flat list of elements in the BEM methodology:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> .block {}
> .block__elem1 {}
> .block__elem2 {}
> .block__elem3 {}
> ```
>
> This allows you to change a block's DOM structure without making changes in the code for each separate element:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <div class="block">
>     <div class="block__elem1">
>         <div class="block__elem2"></div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="block__elem3"></div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> The block's structure changes, but the rules for the elements and their names remain the same.

I understand it as there is only one rule about HTML structure for elements in BEM: *an element has to be inside its block (it doesn't matter how deep)*.

One possible problem that I can imagine for this case is using some of [BEM tree](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#bem-tree) formats. But if you don't need it, I think there's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I been using BEM for sometime and from what I got it's not recommended nor intended to be used like that. You can nest different BEM elements to each other like `menu-block`into`head-block`, but `menu-block` items should not go outside its parent `menu-block`, like you should not put `menu-block__item` at the top of `head-block`. Does it makes sense? :)

To illustrate there are two ways to go. What should be noted here is that depending on the scale of your project and how you build things (component based?). If you don't have a large project and are not doing or reusing the menu else where you can do it both ways. Lets say your menu is huge amount of html/css I would do it like #1

**This is not correct**

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="head__user"></div>
  <div class="head__nav">

    <div class="menu">
       <div class="head__something"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Recommended solution**
Based on [this part of the documentation](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#block). Now you can chop your own header design into blocks, does this below match?

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="head__user"></div>
  <div class="head__nav">
    <div class="menu">
       <div class="menu__something"><img src="" class="menu__image" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first example is correct and the last example isn't, it seems like an element of the element with hacked naming :). Check [this](https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-create-elements-of-elements-block__elem1__elem2) out.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I'm not creating a element in the element, they do `head__menu__something`, there is a point where you have minor "block types" if you will inside your main block. So that would be correct. But as I say in my answer, recommendation is #1.

Comment: It's a hack. Yes, your naming is valid, but `.head__menu-something` element depends on `.head__menu` element, it's not correct.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov it really does not depend on anything, it just a naming to give clear vision on what your element belongs to. In real life your blocks will contain more then 3 divs, lets say those 3 divs all have `a` inside them, how would you name them "correctly"? If not made into seperate blocks by them own.

Comment: If your element belongs to the menu and has no meaning without it, it depends on the menu and should be named `.menu__something`. If not, it should be named `.head__something`, but not `.head__menu-something`.
I use naming by meaning, not by structure or styles.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov makes total sense, that's the way I work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making the potential `head__something` into simply `something`, and then to provide multiple modifications of it. e.g. `something--head` and `something--menu`.

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="head__user"></div>
  <div class="head__nav">
    <div class="menu">
     <div class="something--menu" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="something--head" />
</div>
```

Also, refactoring further, I would consider getting rid of `head__nav` as it probably does not add any richer semantics than `menu`.

```
<div class="head">
  <div class="head__user"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="something--menu" />
  </div>
  <div class="something--head">for those cases where you want <code>something</code> directly descending from <code>head</code></div>
</div>
```